# Async Action Group in Final Builder: Setting the Maximum Concurrent Threads Value Dynamically

Tags: build, build-process, finalbuilder

Anyone knows if it is possible to change this value dynamically?
I want this value to be the same as the number of processors in the machine that the build is running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done by adding a line to the script editor of the action.
Here's the answer I got in the FinalBuilder forum:

http://www.finalbuilder.com/forums/finalbuilder/general-discussion/async-action-group-in-final-builder-setting-the-maximum-concurrent-threads-value-dynamically/